# I want to inherit from Beautifulsoup Class to do the following tasks

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am running on Python 3.5.1 with Beautifulsoup4.

I currently have this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib

class LinkFinder(BeautifulSoup):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

  def handle_starttag(self, name, attrs):
    print(name)
```

When I instantiate the class by the following code:
`findmylink = LinkFinder()` and when I load my html with the following code `findmylink.feed("""<html><head><title>my name is good</title></head><body>hello world</body></html>""",'html5lib')`.

I got the following error in my console:

```
'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I actually wish to duplicate the following sample code (in my case, I wishes to use Beautifulsoup instead of `html.parser`)

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
class LinkFinder(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

   def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print(tag)
```

When I re-instantiate the class by the following code: `findmylink = LinkFinder()` and when I load my html with the following code `findmylink.feed("""<html><head><title>my name is good</title></head><body>hello world</body></html>""")` I get the following output:

```
html
head
title
body
```

which is the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go this way, change your implementation to accept the markup during initialization and [`handle_starttag`](https://github.com/JinnLynn/beautifulsoup/blob/f29f8d278462efb370168f2329b070fa51706013/bs4/__init__.py#L310) to grab all passed args:

```
class LinkFinder(BeautifulSoup):

  def __init__(self, markup):
    super().__init__(markup, 'html.parser')

  def handle_starttag(self, name, namespace, nsprefix, attrs):
    print(name)
```

Initializing with:

```
l = LinkFinder("""<html><head><title>my name is good</title></head><body>hello world</body></html>""")
```

Prints out:

```
html
head
title
body
```

I'm pretty sure the `BeautifulSoup` class has overloaded `__getattr__` to return `None` on non-defined attributes instead of raising `AttributeError`; that's what's causing your error:

```
print(type(BeautifulSoup().feed))
NoneType
print(type(BeautifulSoup().feedededed))
NoneType
```

and, `BeautifulSoup` doesn't have a `feed` function as `HTMLParser` does (it does have a [`_feed`](https://github.com/JinnLynn/beautifulsoup/blob/f29f8d278462efb370168f2329b070fa51706013/bs4/__init__.py#L193) and that calls the underlying `feed` of the `builder` object with `self.markup`) so you get a `None` object which you call.

Comment: that is great of you. However, I discovered I can only make use of "html.parser" with this implementation, other parser like "html5lib" output nothing to the screen. Though, I will stick to this your answer, but do you have an ideas why "html5lib" does not work?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why do you need to use `BeautifulSoup` in such an uncommon way. If you want to simply get the names of all the elements in the HTML tree recursively:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """<html><head><title>my name is good</title></head><body>hello world</body></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")
for elm in soup.find_all():
    print(elm.name)
```

Prints:

```
html
head
title
body
```

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, I am not disposed to this method because I need function that I can always call.